# Simulating information exchange through COM DLL

Tags: dll, com, simulate, plc

I'm working on a program for a user interface for a PLC; however, the PLC automates a huge piece of machinery, and we don't have the room for one at the office for me to test things out on.  It's really inconvenient to try and drive out to one of the manufacturing plants that uses these and try to convince them to let me hook up to their PLCs just so I can test the function of a button.

However, I've picked out the COM DLL that the PLC manufacturers used to get their proprietary interface language (essentially JavaScript, they're not fooling anyone) to communicate with a PLC, and I'm wondering if there's any way to simulate a PLC by figuring out where that DLL tries to get its information from, and feed information into it.  It normally communicates via an ethernet interface, but as for how it accesses the PLC registers, I have absolutely no idea.

Without disassembling the DLL, is anyone aware of a way to accomplish what I want to do?  I've heard of guys rebuilding 3D models from computer games by monitoring DirectX DLLs; is something like that an option here?

Comment: Honestly, I can't even get it decompiled.  I've tried ILSpy, JustDecompile, and dotPeek- none of them will open it.  I'm a little confused by this; if I add the dll as a reference in a visual basic project, Intellisense gives me information about all the functions.  Wouldn't that mean that it's got the right kind of framework for these .NET decompilers?

Comment: in principle if it is a COM DLL then you should be able to use that in your .net or whatever program, however it may be that they do not want 3rd party to use the DLL directly so they may have added guards against that. Since it sounds like your cause is true why don't you directly contact the PLC manufacturer and ask. At least you will then know if it is intended for 3rd party to use it or not, could save you a lot of work.

Comment: I've tried contacting them before for other issues; I'm not sure if it's because they're a German company or if their customer support just really sucks, but I've never gotten any sort of response- I'm usually left to my own devices (pun intended).